# byte array to pdf file with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, byte

I have a byte array and now I want to convert the byte array to a pdf file. I am using the following code, but when I try to see/open the pdf file, it shows

"Adobe reader could not open 'sample.pdf' becauase it is either not a supported file type or because the fiel has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)"

Thanks,
Arefin

Comment: ^ It would be better if you copy the above code, insert it into your question (formatted), and then delete the above comment. Always improve _questions_ rather than adding several addendums in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Before you write the byte array to the response.outputstream, clear it and set the content type to "application/pdf". Flush after use.

Comment: I did with this, but got same result when I try to open the pdf file.

Comment: Make sure that you are rendering only the byte array to the browser. I suggest you use a separate ASP.NET handler for this. Your ASP.NET page may be adding extra characters which is corrupting the PDF stream sent to the browser. BTW, where is your code?